# Tesseract installed is not installed in default location

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have installed tesseract ( build it from the source ) on my rhel machine as specific user without root access as below

```
/> ./autogen.sh
/> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/
/> make 
/> make install
```

When i try to check if it is installer with `tesseract -v` . I am getting `-bash: /usr/local/bin/tesseract: No such file or directory`
(because it is installed on /home/xxx/local)which means that machine looking its default location instead of the location that i installed to.

How can i change this default location to the location that i installed tesseract to ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is command/script/symlink etc. named as `tesseract` in your `PATH`, that points to `/usr/local/bin/tesseract` (probably some previous not correctly uninstalled version?) Try to investigate with command `which tesseract`.

To reach your installation use absolute path (as I expect you do not have `$HOME/local/` in your `PATH`) e.g. `$HOME/local/bin/tesseract`. If you have installed another version of tesseract - expect problems. If you make installation of (any sw) to not standard path (`/usr` or `/usr/local`) you have to be very familiar with your OS and have knowledge how to set it up properly.